# Characterization of rotations of the Riemann sphere?

Tags: complex-analysis

Out of curiosity, is there a nice characterization of the linear fractional transformations which give rotations of the Riemann sphere?

My thinking was a rotation of the Riemann sphere rotates about some axis, and the two points where the sphere intersects the axis will be two fixed points. What more be said of this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there is! See [this](http://www.mth.msu.edu/%7Eshapiro/pubvit/Downloads/RS_Rotation/rotation.html) for details.

"A map of the Riemann sphere to itself is a rotation if and only if the corresponding map induced on the plane by stereographic projection is a linear fractional transformation whose coefficient matrix is unitary."